# Unable to receive transaction number from Paypal after the payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are building a shopping cart website.We have integrated our code with Paypal.We are able to send our cart information to paypal.I also created a sandbox account,made possible settings like turning on Return URL,giving my specific domain url to it and making PDT On as well.But when the payment is completed in sandbox environment.I want it to be redirected to my domain custom page that i have created.The problem is not that it is redirecting,but i'm unable to get the value of Transaction number which is bound to be required with the document that i followed below.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/

Can you let me know,how to fix this issue..I have followed as per the above document link.

Comment: can you show the PDT file?

Comment: Sorry,I don't have any PDT file as such,i have just set up my sandbox merhcant account by turning on the Return Url and PDT option and then followed the document link that i have pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

`How PDT Works:`

When a customer pays you, PayPal sends the transaction ID of the payment to you by appending the transaction ID to a `URL` you specify in your account Profile.

So, you need to specify a return URL where paypal would post the transaction request to.

The return URL is specified like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="your_pdt_file.php">`

Comment: When i'm sending my information,i specified my return url like this,I created a property like this( public string @return { get; set; }),then i gave my custom view page Url like this( paypal.@return = siteUrl + "/Cart/RedirectHandler/PayPal"),this is successfully navigating to my specified view page and then in my view page while sending ( @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.@return)). But when the transaction is completed,I'm redirected back to my return url page,but I'm unable to receieve anything. Can you tell me in detail about the process to follow after Thank you page in Paypal.